# Get Highest values on Diffrent ID's on the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

I have table of bids, each bid has Amount and AuctionID.

I want to SUM/SELECT all the highest bids from each AuctionID..

Example:

The Result of:

`SELECT  AuctionID,Amount, Highest FROM Bids Where Burned=0 ORDER BY Amount DESC`

```
AuctionID   Amount  Highest
   1       44.4400     0
   3       43.7800     0
   2       42.3300     0
   1       22.2200     0
   4       21.2700     0
   1       21.2600     0
   4       21.2500     0
   2       21.2400     0
   1       12.6600     0
   4       12.5200     0
```

It should return **44.44**, **43.78**, **42.33**, **21.27** .

The 'Highest' is a flag that i thought may be helpful it still has no use.
I wanted to see if there is a method to do with without using a Flag.

Comment: Why not it is returning `42.33` for AuctionId= `#2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the highest bids:

```
Select auctionid, max(amount) from auctions group by auctionid
```

To get the overall sum of the highest bids:

```
select sum(v1.max_amount) from
(Select auctionid, max(amount) max_amount from auctions group by auctionid
) as v1
```

Comment: I guess you have to add an alias - updated (sorry, I don't have a MySQL instance to check).

Answer (score 4):

A simple group by clause will do the trick:

```
select AuctionID, MAX(Amount)
from table
group by AuctionID
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT AuctionId, MAX(Amount) FROM TableName GROUP BY AuctionID
```

Comment: SELECT AuctionId, MAX(Amount), (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Auctions WHERE Auctionid = A.AuctionId) AS GrandTotal FROM Auctions A GROUP BY Auctionid